gradle task java.awt.Robot throws java.awt.AWTException: headless environment even if i set it = false
i need simulate keys pressing in my gradle task with Robot class but everytime got exception  java.awt.AWTException: headless environment.
Im try set System.setProperty("java.awt.headless","false") in companion object, init block and plugin apply block and its doesnt work. property = true always. Task runs from terminal

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
